# Unable to register child component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Getting following error.

***Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.***

I am not sure what is wrong with the code. I have followed this link https://michaelnthiessen.com/solve-unknown-custom-element-vue/
I have used Local registration for child component. ( RobotBuilder.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <button class="add-to-cart" @click="addToCart()">Add to Cart</button>
    <div class="top-row">
      <PartSelector />
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
      <PartSelector />
      <PartSelector />
      <PartSelector />
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-row">
      <PartSelector />
    </div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Robot</th>
            <th class="cost">Cost</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(robot,index) in cart" :key="index">
            <td>{{robot.head.title}}</td>
            <td>{{robot.cost}}</td>
            <td>
              <button @click="removeItem([index])">X</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import availableParts from '../data/parts';
import { PartSelector } from './PartSelector.vue';

export default {
  name: 'RobotBuilder',
  components: { PartSelector },
  data() {
    return {
      availableParts,
      cart: [],
      selectedRobot: {
        head: {},
        leftArm: {},
        rightArm: {},
        torso: {},
        base: {},
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    addToCart() {
      const robot = this.selectedRobot;
      const cost = robot.head.cost
        + robot.leftArm.cost
        + robot.torso.cost
        + robot.rightArm.cost
        + robot.base.cost;
      this.cart.push({ ...robot, cost });
    },
    removeItem(index) {
      this.cart.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

PartSelector.vue

```
 <template>
  <div class="part">
    <img :src="selectedPart.src" title="arm"/>
    <button @click="selectPreviousPart()" class="prev-selector"></button>
    <button @click="selectNextPart()" class="next-selector"></button>
    <span class="sale" v-show="selectedPart.onSale">Sale!</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import availableParts from '../data/parts';

const parts = availableParts.heads;

function getPreviousValidIndex(index, length) {
  const deprecatedIndex = index - 1;
  return deprecatedIndex < 0 ? length - 1 : deprecatedIndex;
}

function getNextValidIndex(index, length) {
  const incrementedIndex = index + 1;
  return incrementedIndex > length - 1 ? 0 : incrementedIndex;
}

export default {
  name: 'PartSelector',
  data() {
    return { selectedPartIndex: 0 };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedPart() {
      return parts[this.selectedPartIndex];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    selectNextPart() {
      this.selectedPartIndex = getNextValidIndex(
        this.selectedPartIndex,
        parts.length,
      );
    },
    selectPreviousPart() {
      this.selectedPartIndex = getPreviousValidIndex(
        this.selectedPartIndex,
        parts.length,
      );
    },

  },
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting as default but importing as named import.

In Robot builder, import like this :

```
import PartSelector from './PartSelector.vue';
```